# Почему нету результата в моем коде C#?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Application
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<float> Список_расчетных_нагрузок = new List<float>() { 69.52f, 54.9f, 4.4f, 0.0f, 60.46f, 71.57f, 54.9f, 1.0f, 3.5f, 60.46f, 11.0f, 11.0f, 4.95f, 16.7f, 11.15f, 7.86f, 23.7f };
            List<float> Список_коэффициентов_мощности = new List<float>() { 0.93f, 0.93f, 0.8f, 0.0f, 0.75f, 0.93f, 0.93f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.75f, 0.65f, 0.65f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.79f };
            List<string> Список_имен_панелей = new List<string>() { "ЩЭ", "ЩЭ", "БАУО", "Резерв", "АВР-1", "ЩЭ", "ЩЭ", "ЩУ1", "ЩС-Т1", "АВР-1", "ШУЛ-1", "ЩУЛ-2", "БАУО", "ЩС-ДУ1", "ЩС-Н1", "ЩУ-Пн", "КРМ" };
            List<int> Список_этажей = new List<int>() { 2, 11, 1, 1, 1, 2, 11, 17, 1, 1, 17, 17, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
            List<int> Список_количества_квартир = new List<int>() { 26, 18, 0, 0, 0, 27, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
            List<int> Список_уровней_электрификации = new List<int>() { 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
            List<int> Список_вводов = new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 };
            List<int> Список_не_учитывающихся = new List<int>() { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 };

            void Cycle()
            {
                List<int> Общее_количество_квартир = new List<int>();
                for (int n = 0; n < Список_расчетных_нагрузок.Count; n++)
                {
                    if (Список_количества_квартир[n] > 0)
                    {
                        Общее_количество_квартир.Add(Список_количества_квартир[n]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine(Общее_количество_квартир.Count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Потому что ваша стартовая точка (`static void Main(string[] args)`) - пуста.

Comment: Сперва нужно азы изучить и только потом писать и задавать вопросы.

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/

Comment: Никогда, никогда не называйте переменные кириллицей. И функция Main пуста

Comment: Теперь не пустая этот Main, все равно ошибка

Comment: А про ошибку вы естественно нам не скажете, ну да, зачем, пусть гадают... И почему у вас метод внутри метода?

Comment: @becouse, а что не так с переменными на кириллице?

Comment: С переменными на кириллице не так все. Например каждый символ по 2 байта

Comment: @becouse, в зависимости от кодировки файла же

Comment: Вот вот. Добавьте в кривой код проблемы с байткодами в именах переменных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Добавил вызов метода `Cycle` в `Main`
2. Вынес списки-переменные в класс `Program`, чтобы сделать их видимыми внутри метода `Cycle`, альтернатива - передавать как параметры в сам метод `Cycle`
3. Добавил `Console.ReadKey();`, так мы можем указать программе ожидать ползовательский ввод, программа остановится до тех пор, пока мы не нажмем любую клавишу. Таким образом окно консоли не пропадет сразу после вывода результатов.
4. сделал метод `Cycle` и все переменные статическими, чтобы можно было вызывать без создания  объекта класса `Program`.

   ```
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System;
   namespace Application
   {
       class Program
       {
           static List<float> Список_расчетных_нагрузок = new List<float>() { 69.52f, 54.9f, 4.4f, 0.0f, 60.46f, 71.57f, 54.9f, 1.0f, 3.5f, 60.46f, 11.0f, 11.0f, 4.95f, 16.7f, 11.15f, 7.86f, 23.7f };
           static List<float> Список_коэффициентов_мощности = new List<float>() { 0.93f, 0.93f, 0.8f, 0.0f, 0.75f, 0.93f, 0.93f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.75f, 0.65f, 0.65f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.79f };
           static List<string> Список_имен_панелей = new List<string>() { "ЩЭ", "ЩЭ", "БАУО", "Резерв", "АВР-1", "ЩЭ", "ЩЭ", "ЩУ1", "ЩС-Т1", "АВР-1", "ШУЛ-1", "ЩУЛ-2", "БАУО", "ЩС-ДУ1", "ЩС-Н1", "ЩУ-Пн", "КРМ" };
           static List<int> Список_этажей = new List<int>() { 2, 11, 1, 1, 1, 2, 11, 17, 1, 1, 17, 17, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
           static List<int> Список_количества_квартир = new List<int>() { 26, 18, 0, 0, 0, 27, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
           static List<int> Список_уровней_электрификации = new List<int>() { 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
           static List<int> Список_вводов = new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 };
           static List<int> Список_не_учитывающихся = new List<int>() { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 };

           static void Main(string[] args)
           {
               Cycle();
               Console.ReadKey();
           }

               static void Cycle()
               {
                   List<int> Общее_количество_квартир = new List<int>();
                   for (int n = 0; n < Список_расчетных_нагрузок.Count; n++)
                   {
                       if (Список_количества_квартир[n] > 0)
                       {
                           Общее_количество_квартир.Add(Список_количества_квартир[n]);
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           continue;
                       }
                   }

                   Console.WriteLine(Общее_количество_квартир.Count);
               }
       }
   }
   ```