# Как сделать чтобы списки были доступны во всех методах C#?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Application
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Data()
        {
            List<float> Список_расчетных_нагрузок = new List<float>() { 69.52f, 54.9f, 4.4f, 0.0f, 60.46f, 71.57f, 54.9f, 1.0f, 3.5f, 60.46f, 11.0f, 11.0f, 4.95f, 16.7f, 11.15f, 7.86f, 23.7f };
            List<float> Список_коэффициентов_мощности = new List<float>() { 0.93f, 0.93f, 0.8f, 0.0f, 0.75f, 0.93f, 0.93f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.75f, 0.65f, 0.65f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.79f };
            List<string> Список_имен_панелей = new List<string>() { "ЩЭ", "ЩЭ", "БАУО", "Резерв", "АВР-1", "ЩЭ", "ЩЭ", "ЩУ1", "ЩС-Т1", "АВР-1", "ШУЛ-1", "ШУЛ-2", "БАУО", "ЩС-ДУ1", "ЩС-Н1", "ЩУ-Пн", "КРМ" };
            List<int> Список_этажей = new List<int>() { 2, 11, 1, 1, 1, 2, 11, 17, 1, 1, 17, 17, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
            List<int> Список_количества_квартир = new List<int>() { 26, 18, 0, 0, 0, 27, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
            List<int> Список_уровней_электрификации = new List<int>() { 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
            List<int> Список_вводов = new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 };
            List<int> Список_не_учитывающихся = new List<int>() { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          for (n = 0; n < Список_расчетных_нагрузок.Count; n++)
          {
              Console.WriteLine(Список_имен_панелей[n]);
          }
        }

        static int Количество_квартир_вводов(int Ввод_N)
        {
            List<int> Количество_квартир_отфильтрованное = new List<int>();
            for (int n = 0; n < Список_количества_квартир.Count; n++)
            {
                if (Список_вводов[n] == Ввод_N && Список_количества_квартир[n] > 0 && Список_уровней_электрификации[n] > 0 && Список_не_учитывающихся[n] == 0) { Количество_квартир_отфильтрованное.Add(Список_количества_квартир[n]); }
                else { continue; }
            }
            int Общее_количество_квартир = Количество_квартир_отфильтрованное.Sum();
            return Общее_количество_квартир;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ого...трэш...переменные на русском ) сразу 1с вспомнил )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    //public static void Data()
    //{
        static List<float> Список_расчетных_нагрузок = new List<float>() { 69.52f, 54.9f, 4.4f, 0.0f, 60.46f, 71.57f, 54.9f, 1.0f, 3.5f, 60.46f, 11.0f, 11.0f, 4.95f, 16.7f, 11.15f, 7.86f, 23.7f };
        static List<float> Список_коэффициентов_мощности = new List<float>() { 0.93f, 0.93f, 0.8f, 0.0f, 0.75f, 0.93f, 0.93f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.75f, 0.65f, 0.65f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.79f };
        static List<string> Список_имен_панелей = new List<string>() { "ЩЭ", "ЩЭ", "БАУО", "Резерв", "АВР-1", "ЩЭ", "ЩЭ", "ЩУ1", "ЩС-Т1", "АВР-1", "ШУЛ-1", "ШУЛ-2", "БАУО", "ЩС-ДУ1", "ЩС-Н1", "ЩУ-Пн", "КРМ" };
        static List<int> Список_этажей = new List<int>() { 2, 11, 1, 1, 1, 2, 11, 17, 1, 1, 17, 17, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
        static List<int> Список_количества_квартир = new List<int>() { 26, 18, 0, 0, 0, 27, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        static List<int> Список_уровней_электрификации = new List<int>() { 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        static List<int> Список_вводов = new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 };
        static List<int> Список_не_учитывающихся = new List<int>() { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
    //}
```

Comment: `static` [потеряли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1080103/179763)

Comment: @tym32167 точно